# Cmake very simple set failure

Tags: cmake

I trying to start using cmake with the simplest helloworld example, in ubuntu 12.04, cmake 2.8.7.  First I tried the one from:

http://www.elpauer.org/stuff/learning_cmake.pdf

```
project( helloworld )
set( SRCFILES helloWorld.cpp )
add_executable( helloWorld ${SRCFILES} )
```

I have only a source file called "helloWorld.cpp" by the side of the CMakeLists.txt.  I created a directory called "configure", went inside and called "cmake ..".  I get the following:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Trying to figure out what wrong I got all the following changes:

```
project( helloworld )
set( SRCFILES helloWorld.cpp )
message ( "src ${SRCFILES}" )
set(x helloWorld.cpp)
set(y 2)
message(${x}${y})
message(${x}${y})
message(${SRCFILES})

add_executable( helloWorld ${SRCFILES} )
add_executable( helloWorld ${x} )
add_executable( helloWorld helloWorld.cpp )
```

The results again finish with:

```
...
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
src 
helloWorld.cpp2
helloWorld.cpp2
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (message):
  message called with incorrect number of arguments


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:11 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:12 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Finally, the trivial

```
project( helloworld )
add_executable( helloWorld helloWorld.cpp )
```

Fails with:

```
...
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (add_executable):
  add_executable called with incorrect number of arguments


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Before each trial I remove all files within compile.  I just can't figure out what is missing and why the variable is set.. not set... useless?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This all looks fine to me and works on Windows with CMake v2.8.10.2 (although the 3 `add_executable` commands needed different exe names).  Can you try removing all the spaces after all the `(`s to see if that fixes it?  It looks like the `set(x helloWorld.cpp)` worked, but the `set( SRCFILES helloWorld.cpp )` didn't.

Comment: Removing spaces did not work :(.  Anyway, `set(x ...)` works only in `message`, but when used in `add_executable` it still gives an error.  The other issue is, I have been configuring lots of source distributions with cmake and it works just fine, so I really don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Yeah, but the `add_executable` calls all had spaces too after the braces - did you remove those too (I'm grasping at straws really I'm afraid).

Comment: Try to add `project(helloworld C CXX)`.

Comment: Wow! I added the `C CXX` and it began to work! The odd thing is that now it works without it as well :S.  Well, I really do appreciate your help, sorted out! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably copied the same corrupted text from a webpage as I did. There must be some hidden character in the text. Re-writing the line manually solved it also for me.